# LPIC-1(101-102) exam , what community think about it and which material is advise for it

Tags: linux, certificate

I want to do LPIC-1 (101-102) exam. What community opinion about it ? What is preferable books/material for prepare to it

Answer (score 0):

I too am wanting to take the test. Here is a link to LPI's recommended study resources http://www.lpimarketplace.com/category-s/1513.htm

Answer (score 0):

you can find a whole concept what to read at the LPI official website.

```
https://www.lpi.org/how-to-get-certified/preparing-for-my-exam
```

and here is good LPIC1 Study Guide:

```
https://jadi.gitbooks.io/lpic1/content/
```

Enjoy!